# How to produce theorems in which the color of heading and body of the theorem my differ?

Tags: color, theorems

I have tried the following code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,xcolor}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{color}{blue}{\begin{thm}\begin{color}{red}{The     theorem.}\end{thm}}\end{color}
\end{document}
```

But it isn't working. So, my questions are the following,

1. How can I solve the problem? As example, what will be the code for the following,

> The heading will be colored blue and the body of the theorem will be colored, red.

2. What will be the codes of the same if the documentclass be `book` or `memoir`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is with the `thmtools` interface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,xcolor}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\color{blue}\normalfont\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\color{red}\normalfont\itshape,
]{colored}

\declaretheorem[
  style=colored,
  name=Theorem,
]{thm}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
The theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about other documentclasses?

Comment: @user170039 I see no problem in using the same code.

Comment: would it be possible to define it like this with a parameter for the color? E.g. you say `headfont=\color{#1}\normalfont\bfseries` in the `\declaretheoremstyle` call, and use it like `\begin{colorthm}[red] ... \end{colorthm}`.

Comment: Is it possible to apply a theorem style ad hoc to a theorem environment that's inside the body of the document rather than creating in the preamble a specialized theorem environment that uses this style?

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve your result by declaring a `newtheoremstyle` as detailed on page 9 of the `amsthm` documentation:

```
% declare a new theorem style
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below 
{\itshape\color{red}}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries\color{blue}}% Theorem head font
{.}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
```

You can then use it as:

```
% use the new theorem style
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
```

Here's a complete example, the output is as in egreg's answer.

```
% arara: pdflatex
 \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,xcolor}

% declare a new theorem style
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below 
{\itshape\color{red}}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries\color{blue}}% Theorem head font
{.}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head 
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

% use the new theorem style
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
The theorem.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `color{red}` might have the side effect off increasing the vertical space separating environments. Sadly, I cannot reproduce this issue now.