# Resetting or custom numbering in thmtools

Tags: numbering, tufte, thmtools

I'm using thmtools in tufte-handout class, with styles given by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283580/153093) for declaring properties assiciated with various systems. I searched in [Thmtools User's Guide](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/doc/texlive-latex-extra-doc/latex/thmtools/thmtools.pdf) for a custom number or resetting under the same section at section *3.2 Known keys to \declaretheorem*. But I'm not able to work out with the keys given as

```
parent
numberwithin
within
sibling
numberlike
sharenumber
numbered
```

Here is my MWE, where changes are to be required.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,xcolor}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\color{blue}\normalfont\bfseries,
bodyfont=\color{black}\normalfont\itshape,
]{colored}

\declaretheorem[
style=colored,
name=Property,
]{mydef}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod    
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
\begin{mydef}
    XYZ11
\begin{proof}
    fffddffd
\end{proof}
\end{mydef}
\begin{mydef}
    XYZ12
    \begin{proof}
        fffddffd
    \end{proof}
\end{mydef}
\begin{mydef}
    XYZ13
    \begin{proof}
        fffddffd
    \end{proof}
\end{mydef}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod    
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
\begin{mydef}
    XYZ21
    \begin{proof}
        fffddffd
    \end{proof}
\end{mydef}
\begin{mydef}
    XYZ22
    \begin{proof}
        fffddffd
    \end{proof}
\end{mydef}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want **Property 4.** to to be set to **Property 1.** and then **Property 5.** to be as **Property 2.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to reset counter automatically?

If you allow set it up manually, simply use `\setcounter{mydef}{0}` before to use again the `mydef`.

*Off-topic:* you can use `lipsum` package to produce dummy text, for example, `\lipsum` or `\lipsum[2]`.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}                 % dummy text

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\color{blue}\normalfont\bfseries,
bodyfont=\color{black}\normalfont\itshape,
]{colored}

\declaretheorem[
style=colored,
name=Property,
]{mydef}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mydef}
    XYZ11
\begin{proof}
    fffddffd
\end{proof}
\end{mydef}
\begin{mydef}
    XYZ12
    \begin{proof}
        fffddffd
    \end{proof}
\end{mydef}
\begin{mydef}
    XYZ13
    \begin{proof}
        fffddffd
    \end{proof}
\end{mydef}
\lipsum[2]
\setcounter{mydef}{0}
\begin{mydef}
    XYZ21
    \begin{proof}
        fffddffd
    \end{proof}
\end{mydef}
\begin{mydef}
    XYZ22
    \begin{proof}
        fffddffd
    \end{proof}
\end{mydef}
\end{document}
```

[image]